# htaccess redirect of a modrewritten page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have written a mod rewrite that turns every **/part_listing.php?id=??** page into **/part/??** page.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^part/([0-9]+)/?$ part_listing.php?id=$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/part$ /
```

I have tons of **/part_listing.php?id=??** links on many pages, going through it one by one would be a pain.

Is there a way to redirect every **/part_listing.php?id=??** page to the **/part/??** page?

I tried this but it seems to give a internal server error.

```
Redirect ^part/([0-9]+)/?$ part_listing.php?id=$1
```

thanks for the upcoming assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

# redirect for old links    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+part_listing\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /part/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^part/([0-9]+)/?$ part_listing.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: you are a champ, thank you so much for helping me out. Can I also just copy and paste it a few times so i can use it for other links such as **category.php?id=** and **profile.php?id=** or is there an easier way instead of creating a huge .htacess file?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you can use same pattern for `category.php?id=` URLs.